# ADFS in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-3.5, adfs

Suggest me with some informative links about working with ADFS in Asp.Net 3.5 and its related downloads.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with ADFS, are you looking for a single sign on solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend checking out Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) if you do not need to tie directly into Active Directory.  Either way Microsoft just dropped their [Identity Training Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=148795) which will cover both.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the training kit as suggested before or the "[Claims Identity Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)"